# How to add a responsive menu bar to html website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a responsive menu looks like following in my website.

[image]

I've already made my website responsive with CSS media queries. I want to add this kind of menu when the `max-width : 479px` .

This is my Project: [Link to project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hQ3s3q72rLbWxDM2FKd29ZSnM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like this.For me it looks like drop down menu. It is just an suggestion

Fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/tg9n3/1/)

```
<div class="dd_menu_wrapper">
    <!-- MENU -->
    <label for="dd-0" class="dd_label">Navigation</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="dd_toggle" id="dd-0">
    <ul class="dd_menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dd_parent">
            <label for="dd-1">Products</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="dd_trigger" id="dd-1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dd_parent">
            <label for="dd-2">Resources</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="dd_trigger" id="dd-2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">This is samplek</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*  _______________________________________________

    01 MENU BAR
    _______________________________________________  */
 .dd_menu_wrapper {
    width: 479px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index:9999;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:21px;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.dd_menu_wrapper a, .dd_menu_wrapper label {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition:color .3s;
    -moz-transition:color .3s;
    -o-transition:color .3s;
    -ms-transition:color .3s;
    transition:color .3s;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dd_menu_wrapper a:hover,
.dd_menu_wrapper label:hover,
.dd_parent:hover label {
    color:#000;
    background-color:#eff0f1;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dd_menu {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
    background: #565a5c;
}
.dd_menu:before, .dd_menu:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.dd_menu:after {
    clear: both;
}
.dd_menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.dd_menu > li {
    float: left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dd_menu li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
}
.dd_menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #eff0f1;
    color:#000;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent {
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent ul li a:hover {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent > label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent > label a:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent > label a:active {
    color:#000000;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent > label a:focus {
    color:#000000;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent > label a:visited {
    color:#000000;
}
.dd_menu li.dd_parent > label a {
    color:#000000;
}
/*  _______________________________________________

    02 DROP DOWNS
    _______________________________________________  */
 .dd_menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 41px;
    left: -999em;
    min-width: 170px;
    background: #eff0f1;
    color:#000;
}
.dd_menu .dd_trigger {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
/*  _______________________________________________

    03 DESKTOP VERSION
    _______________________________________________  */
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .dd_menu > li:hover > ul {
        left:auto;
    }
    .dd_toggle, .dd_label {
        display: none;
    }
}
/*  _______________________________________________

    04 MOBILE VERSION
    _______________________________________________  */
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .dd_label {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color:#ffffff;
        background: #565a5c;
    }
    .dd_label:after {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        content: url("../images/toggle.png");
        float: right;
    }
    .dd_toggle, .dd_toggle:checked {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .dd_menu {
        position: absolute;
        background: #565a5c;
        opacity:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    .dd_menu > li {
        padding-right: 0;
        float: none;
    }
    .dd_menu > li:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .dd_menu li ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        top:auto;
        left:auto;
        width:auto;
        z-index: 999;
        visibility: visible;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left:12px;
        background: none;
    }
    .dd_toggle:checked + .dd_menu {
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    .dd_menu .dd_trigger + ul {
        max-height:0;
        opacity:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    .dd_menu .dd_trigger:checked + ul {
        position: static;
        max-height:999px;
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
        z-index: 999;
        background-color:#eff0f1;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this code done by you ? can you just download my project and integrate the responsive menu ?

Comment: @user3736954 : here we can help you by correcting your mistakes and suggest code..But can not work on behalf of you.. For that you have to Hire .. ;)

Comment: @user3736954 Sorry i dont  have that much to integrate. I guess you can do it easily

Answer (score 1):

In  smaller screen hide your menu with css .

> ```
> .menu { display:none; }
> ```

make one button whos hide on larger screen and visible in smaller screen with help of media queries , then you can add java script like this

`$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#buttonId").click(function (){
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

The image you included is probablly using Bootstrap Framework to achieve the responsiveness.
You can have a look at it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/).

You will have to write CSS [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to achieve that. You can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) to find how can you make a responsive navbar.

Comment: Yeah , I know , but it can be done with Pure css and Js too . Now i'm unable to make the whole website again with bootstrap. so i need a solution with css and js

Comment: @user3736954: I can understand that, I have updated the answer and included a specific tutorial, you can refer to that. :)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/DwrGK/32/)**</kbd>

css

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header {
    background-color:black;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2%;
}

#logo {
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 50px);
    max-width:280px;
    height:40px;
    background-image:url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-gjxoCu8Fu3c/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAA-Wk/mVaqfjXjn4k/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg'); /* your logo here! */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    /*background-size:100%;*/
}

nav {
    float:right;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.navitem {
    color:#999;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px;
}

.navitem:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
}

.navitem:hover {
    color:white;
}

#smartbutton {
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:7px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:none;
}

.buttonline {
    background-color:#999;
    height:3px;
    margin-top:4px;
}

.buttonline:first-child {
    margin-top:0px;
}

/* standard menu */
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) 
{
    #smartbutton {
        display:none;
    }

    nav {
        display:inline-block !important;
    }
}

/* smart menu */
@media only screen and (max-width:479px) 
{
    #smartbutton {
        display:inline-block;
    }

    nav {
        display:none;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        top:5px;
    }

    .navitem {
        border-top:1px solid #999;
        display:block;
        margin:0px;
    }

    .navitem:hover {
        background-color:#333;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <a id="logo" href="#"></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" class="navitem">Link1</a>
        <a href="#" class="navitem">Link2</a>
        <a href="#" class="navitem">Link3</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

jquery

```
// create smartbutton
$('nav').before('<div id="smartbutton"></div>');
$('#smartbutton').append('<div class="buttonline"></div>');
$('#smartbutton').append('<div class="buttonline"></div>');
$('#smartbutton').append('<div class="buttonline"></div>');

// add click listener
$('#smartbutton').click(function(event) 
{
  $('nav').animate({height:'toggle'},200);
});
```

Comment: This is what i just wanted :) Can you just integrate this code to my project ? my project is attached in the description .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a framework? Here for [example](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) .

They have a component which is pretty much what you want.
And [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-customize-the-foundation-4-top-bar--webdesign-14675)  you will find an article on how to style it to your liking.

Comment: yeah but the thing is I've already finished the site , so i wont re-make it using a framework only because of the nav bar . and i've made it responsive with media queries so there's no need to use a framework :S all i just need is to integrate a responsive menu for the small scale size

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its better to use Frameworks like **Twitter Bootstrap** or **Foundation** but as I've seen you example above I think it is Twitter Bootstrap. It is simple to use the frameworks.

Here is tutorials of Twitter Bootstrap. I give you the navbar link for you to see the example.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

See the examples there.. just make you browser smaller for you to see how it is responsive..

I hope it will help you.